# React - setState to True for All Empty Input Fields on Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, setstate

I'd like to dynamically setState to true, if an input field is empty. This is so I can style each input field when it is empty via css class when its' state is true.

In my current code, it will run through the loop and set the last empty item to true, even though all inputs are empty. In my mind, I thought it should set everything that's empty to true, but looks like the loop will only recognize the last iteration.

How do I setState to true for all inputs that are empty?

HTML:

```
<form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input className="form-input" type="text" name="name">

  <label>Email</label>
  <input className="form-input" type="text" name="email">

  <label>Message</label>
  <input className="form-input" type="text" name="message">
</Form>
```

State:

```
this.state = {
  errors: {
    name: false,
    email: false,
    message: false,
  },
};
```

JS:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {

let inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
  if (inputFields[i].value === '') {

    let inputName = inputFields[i].name;

    this.setState({
      errors: {
        [inputName]: true,
      },
    });
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `setState` merges only the root keys into the state.
In your case, your state is `{ errors { ... } }`, by doing `setState({ error: { ... } })`, react replaces your whole error object inside the state.

You can craft the `errors` object in the loop, and do `setState` only once:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  let inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input');
  let errors = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
    if (inputFields[i].value === '') {
      let inputName = inputFields[i].name;
      errors[inputName] = true;
    }
  }
  this.setState({errors});
}
```

That is the better approach. But, it might help to understand how `setState` works if you also look at this approach:

You can move the keys from `errors` to the root of your state, so react merges them into the state instead of replacing them.

```
this.state = {
 nameError: false,
 emailError: false,
 messageError: false,
};
```

and

```
this.setState({
  [`${inputName}Error`]: true,
});
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution! Clarification on this line: "errors[inputName] = true;" - I understand that it's populating errors object but how is it doing it? don't understand the syntax since there's not space between errors and [inputName]. thanks

Comment: @EricNguyen I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. When you have an object, you can read or write properties by using square brackets if the property is stored as a string inside a variable. So `errors['name']=true` and `error.name=true` are the same.

Comment: I would suggest reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp)

Comment: Thanks @Amir I understand now, it's the brackets that was throwing me off, but I read up on it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you require while also retaining your components current state structure, consider the following changes to `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input');

    /* Define errors object which will contain updated errors state based
    on form values */
    let errors = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
    if (inputFields[i].value === '') {

        let inputName = inputFields[i].name;

        /* Gather all error state into a single object */
        errors = { ...errors, [inputName]: true };
    }
    }

    /* Call setState once - this is more efficient and simplifies updating
    the nested errors object */
    this.setState((state) => {

        /* Replace nested error state with newly defined errors object */
        return { ...state, errors }
    });
}
```

Here we take advantage of the behavior of `errors` state in relation to the form, in that it can be recreated based on the values of form inputs during the `handleSubmit` function.

First, an `errors` object is locally defined and composed based on the value of form inputs. This `errors` object captures the new error state of the form based on input values. Finally, `setState` is called once via a callback. Here, the locally created `errors` object is specified as the new nested `errors` state of the component.